# Playing Audiobooks (m4b media format) using AudioQueue services | iPhone

Tags: iphone, xcode, audioqueueservices

I am working on developing an iPhone app to play music. Am using AudioQueue services to play the audio files. App plays all media files correctly, but the app fails to play audiobooks, which I think is because they are different media format (.m4b) from other media items in my library (mp3).

I am sure I need to change how am initializing the audioqueue or AVAssetReaderTrackOutput to play media with different file format but am not sure how.

Can anyone point me to right direction.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have figured it out, the issue was not because of the media format. The Audiobook I was trying to play in my app was DRM protected, so the was unable to play it.

Thanks